# How to take the derivative of list inside a .dat file from Mathematica using Python?

Tags: python, wolfram-mathematica

I have a .dat file from Mathematica. It has two columns: the first column represents the pre-quench relative chemical potential ($\theta_{0}$), and the second column represents the average work done ($\braket{W}$).

```
0.0001  1.968765727
0.03151592653589794 1.526403743
0.06293185307179587 1.315922249
0.0943477796076938  1.181680326
0.12576370614359172 1.092500991
0.15717963267948964 1.034055677
0.1885955592153876  0.9986171379
0.22001148575128554 0.9811207217
0.25142741228718346 0.9778559454
0.2828433388230814  0.9864639035
0.3142592653589793  1.005123779
0.3456751918948773  1.032472433
0.3770911184307752  1.06748456
0.4085070449666731  1.109396204
0.4399229715025711  1.157654853
0.471338898038469   1.211886853
0.5027548245743669  1.271876803
0.5341707511102649  1.337555877
0.5655866776461628  1.408997391
0.5970026041820607  1.486418909
0.6284185307179586  1.570190989
0.6598344572538566  1.660731115
0.6912503837897546  1.759140881
0.7226663103256524  1.865661911
0.7540822368615504  1.982382946
0.7854981633974484  2.110586591
0.8169140899333462  2.252795219
0.8483300164692442  2.410700136
0.8797459430051422  2.589771972
0.9111618695410401  2.794071187
0.942577796076938   3.033575331
0.9739937226128359  3.323391524
1.0054096491487339  3.699588638
1.0368255756846319  3.905513036
1.0682415022205298  3.365482708
1.0996574287564276  2.902485831
1.1310733552923256  2.502188583
1.1624892818282235  2.154786056
1.1939052083641215  1.851708306
1.2253211349000195  1.585798632
1.2567370614359172  1.351316619
1.2881529879718152  1.122552869
1.3195689145077132  0.9609250081
1.3509848410436112  0.7970216327
1.3824007675795091  0.649843702
1.4138166941154071  0.5169416572
1.4452326206513049  0.3961682839
1.4766485471872028  0.2855755599
1.5080644737231008  0.1836374567
1.5394804002589988  -0.0843703707
1.5708963267948968  0.0002668209559
1.6023122533307945  0.2516937775
1.6337281798666925  0.492273888
1.6651441064025905  0.7253692214
1.6965600329384884  0.9500449098
1.7279759594743864  1.166259793
1.7593918860102844  1.374218726
1.7908078125461822  1.573771245
1.8222237390820801  1.765135571
1.853639665617978   1.948242241
1.885055592153876   2.123273373
1.916471518689774   2.290564007
1.9478874452256718  2.450236891
1.9793033717615698  2.601330042
2.010719298297468   2.745413105
2.0421352248333657  2.881912668
2.073551151369264   2.986664867
2.1049670779051617  3.13340867
2.13638300444106    3.248402463
2.1677989309769576  3.355004915
2.1992148575128554  3.457560413
2.2306307840487536  3.55222602
2.2620467105846513  3.64009798
2.2934626371205495  3.722207193
2.3248785636564473  3.796860739
2.356294490192345   3.866975081
2.3877104167282432  3.931456933
2.419126343264141   3.989416888
2.450542269800039   4.038039032
2.481958196335937   4.089254811
2.5133741228718347  4.118176178
2.544790049407733   4.167857922
2.5762059759436307  4.200698856
2.607621902479529   4.22397227
2.6390378290154266  4.244919941
2.670453755551325   4.258992793
2.7018696820872226  4.267133062
2.7332856086231203  4.268776953
2.7647015351590185  4.263238875
2.7961174616949163  4.249339865
2.8275333882308145  4.225337816
2.858949314766712   4.18946278
2.89036524130261    4.139231773
2.921781167838508   4.070571301
2.953197094374406   3.978907532
2.984613020910304   3.856762428
3.016028947446202   3.693401012
3.0474448739820996  3.473508407
3.078860800517998   3.17101391
3.1102767270538956  2.735631484
```

When I plotted this in Mathematica, I noticed a cusp at $\theta_{0} = 1.02678266592038$. In order to verify whether this is really a discontinuity, I need to take the derivative of $\braket{W}$ with respect to $\theta_{0}$. I have done it in Mathematica but my resulting plot is not convincing. Hence, I want to try it in python. However, I'm clueless on how to start it. Any suggestions will be of great help. Thanks!

Editted: 
Mathematica Code

```
a = Import['file.dat']
b = Interpolation[a, Method -> "Spline"]
c = b'
```

Comment: And you are sure switching the programming languages will help? Why don't you provide the data you used and show what you have done in Mathematica?

Comment: This is what I did in Mathematica: (1) a = Import['file.dat'], (2) b = Interpolation[a, Method -> "Spline"], (3) c = b'.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show your Mathematica code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you have problems inspecting the derivative. Following the exact same approach, you pointed out, the derivate shows where the discontinuities are. You can use this here to get your data in Mathematica format

```
Import["http://halirutan.github.io/Mathematica-SE-Tools/decode.m"]["https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfXo1.png"]
```

and then

```
ip = Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> 3, Method -> "Spline"];
Plot[{ip[x], .1 ip'[x]}, {x, 0.0001, 3.11}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

That being said, you can search for the root of the first derivative in this interval with

```
FindRoot[ip'[x], {x, .8, 1.2}]

(* {x -> 1.03119} *)
```

Comment: I'll look into it. Thanks!